# how to store "networkx info" output in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I want to store output of following NetworkX output into a Pandas data frame:

```py
for i in (node_id):
    G.remove_nodes_from([i])
    (nx.info(G))
```

Current output looks like follows:

```
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 262
Number of edges: 455
Average degree:   3.4733
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 261
Number of edges: 425
Average degree:   3.2567
```

Please, could you tell me a way to store these output into a data frame or dictionary

Comment: Can you provide minimal code to get to set up the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.info` outputs a string, you can feed it to `pandas.read_csv`:

```
import networkx as nx
import io
import pandas as pd

# dummy graph
G = nx.star_graph(5)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(nx.info(G)), sep=':\s*', engine='python', names=['attribute', 'value'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         attribute   value
0             Name     NaN
1             Type   Graph
2  Number of nodes       6
3  Number of edges       5
4   Average degree  1.6667
```

*NB. Note that `nx.info` is deprecated and will be removed in networkx 3*